# Windows Docker container can't access internet

Tags: networking, nat, docker, docker-for-windows

I'm running on a windows 10 pc. I installed Docker for Windows and enabled both Containers and Hyper-V in windows features. Virtualization is enabled in the bios.

When I run `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver ping google.com` I receive the following:

```
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

And when I run `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver ping 8.8.8.8`, I get the following:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.18.81.109: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 1, Lost = 3 (75% loss),
```

If I run either from my host machine, they work appropriately.

I have run the debug script here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/live/windows-server-container-tools/Debug-ContainerHost and all tests passed.

Any idea why my container can't route to the outside internet?

Comment: Need detailed information about how you created this container.

Comment: couple comments: first, `ping` might not work, even if networking is working, so try something else (e.g., `curl` or `wget`); second, maybe it's a windows firewall issue blocking you; or, possibly multiple ethernet adapters are enabled -- or a slew of related issues, see for ideas: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very unsatisfactory answer, but after installing all windows updates, uninstalling Docker, disabling/re-enabling Hyper V and Containers, and re-installing Docker, I got it working.

Best I can tell, it was a missing Windows Update.